# Getting NameNotFoundException when trying to get name of app from StatusBarNotification

Tags: java, android, notifications, mobile-development

I am using a notification listener and trying to get the name of the app that sent the notification. I tried using the PackageManager class to get the name of the app, however, I keep getting a NameNotFoundException every time I get a notification. Here is my code:

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    private final ArrayList<Integer> postedIds = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        ArrayList<Integer> connectedThreadNotifications = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BluetoothConnectionThread bluetoothConnectionThread :
                Utils.getCurrentlyRunningThreads()) {
            connectedThreadNotifications.add(bluetoothConnectionThread.getNotificationID());
        }

        if (sbn.getId() != 800 && !connectedThreadNotifications.contains(sbn.getId())) {
            if (!postedIds.contains(sbn.getId())) {
                postedIds.add(sbn.getId());

                HashMap<String, Object> notification = new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                    ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(sbn.getPackageName(), 0);
                    String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString();
                    notification.put("appName", appName);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    notification.put("appName", "Unknown");
                }
                notification.put("title", sbn.getNotification().extras.get("android.title"));
                notification.put("subText", sbn.getNotification().extras.get("android.subText"));
                notification.put("text", sbn.getNotification().extras.get("android.text"));
                notification.put("infoText", sbn.getNotification().extras.get("android.infoText"));

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                System.out.println(gson.toJson(notification));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        if (postedIds.contains(sbn.getId())) {
            postedIds.remove((Integer) sbn.getId());
        }
    }

    public void broadcastNotification() {

    }
}
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this issue, seems like Android 11 has changed the permission model of those APIs, see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

Unfortunately as far as I can tell, adding this permission is the only way to get app name of a notification now.